# skip if match all but n columns of previous line

Tags: awk

I have a large csv file with consecutive repeated rows except for the time related columns (columns 1, 2, 3, 4) I want to skip except for the first occurence (non-consecutive repeated rows are ok).

Is there a more efficient way than the below code? (I also don't want to painfully hard code that condition, say when I have more than 9 columns)

```bash
 awk -F"," -v OFS="," 'p[5]!=$5 || p[6]!=$6 || p[7]!=$7 || p[8]!=$8 || p[9]!=$9 {for (i = 5; i <= 9; i++) {p[i] = $i}; print $0}' file_path
```

---

Example input:

```
a,z,k,d,5,6,7,8,9
b,x,j,d,5,6,7,8,9
c,c,l,e,8,9,1,2,3
d,v,k,r,8,9,1,2,3
e,b,j,e,9,1,2,3,4
f,n,h,t,5,6,7,8,9
g,m,g,w,6,3,4,5,6
h,a,f,q,4,5,6,7,8
i,s,d,w,4,5,6,7,8
i,s,d,w,4,5,6,7,8
```

Desired output:

```
a,z,k,d,5,6,7,8,9
c,c,l,e,8,9,1,2,3
e,b,j,e,9,1,2,3,4
f,n,h,t,5,6,7,8,9
g,m,g,w,6,3,4,5,6
h,a,f,q,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '{prev=key; key=$0; sub(/([^,]*,){4}/,"",key)} key != prev' file
a,z,k,d,5,6,7,8,9
c,c,l,e,8,9,1,2,3
e,b,j,e,9,1,2,3,4
f,n,h,t,5,6,7,8,9
g,m,g,w,6,3,4,5,6
h,a,f,q,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Is regex expected to perform faster than hardcoding field-field comparisons? I've just realised for my use case I can afford to hardcode by programmatically writing the shell command

Comment: Probably as it's one operation vs many but you could always test it to see.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have space if the fields

```
$ sed 's/,/ /4' file | uniq -f1 | sed 's/ /,/'
```

since `uniq` doesn't work with arbitrary delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex="([^,]+,){4}" }                     # match first 4x "column," sets
      { match($0,regex)
        curr=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)            # strip off first 4x "column," sets
        if (curr == prev) next                    # if the same as previous row then go to next input
        else { print; prev=curr }                 # else print current line and set prev = current line
      }
' file
```

This generates:

```
a,z,k,d,5,6,7,8,9
c,c,l,e,8,9,1,2,3
e,b,j,e,9,1,2,3,4
f,n,h,t,5,6,7,8,9
g,m,g,w,6,3,4,5,6
h,a,f,q,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed

```
$ sed -En 'G;/^([^,]*,){4}([^\n]*)\n([^,]*,){4}\2/d;h;P' input_file
a,z,k,d,5,6,7,8,9
c,c,l,e,8,9,1,2,3
e,b,j,e,9,1,2,3,4
f,n,h,t,5,6,7,8,9
g,m,g,w,6,3,4,5,6
h,a,f,q,4,5,6,7,8
```